# Sort list based on the index value without sort() or sorted()

Tags: python, list

I have a list that I want to sort by the index without using sort() or sorted()

```
list2d=[[6,7,8,9],
       [8,8,8,8],
       [97,64,3,11]]
```

So if I sort by index[3] the list sorts too:

```
list2d=[[8,8,8,8]
        [6,7,8,9],
       [97,64,3,11]]
```

I have this so far but it is only obviously for 1dlists:

```
for i in range(0,len(list2d)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(list2d)):
            if (list2d[i]>list2d[j]):
                list2d[i],list2d[j]=list2d[j],list2d[i]
```

Comment: Use any shorting method like bubble shorting

Comment: how would i use it for 2d list though. Like i dont want to sort within the sperate lists. Just the 2d list as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how:

```
for i in range(0,len(list2d)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(list2d)):
            if (list2d[i][3]>list2d[j][3]):
                list2d[i],list2d[j]=list2d[j],list2d[i]
```

By just replacing

```
if (list2d[i]>list2d[j]):
```

With

```
if (list2d[i][3]>list2d[j][3]):
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Was just having trouble with the 2nd last line